# How to build resource files in to dll while maintaining their folder structure?

Tags: dll, resources

Is there a way to build a folder containing various resource files into a dll? The folder may contain sub-folders, and I want to keep the folder structure of these files so that I can access the files from the dll with relative path.

I'm using visual studio but it seems I can only add a resource file without sub-folders. Can you give me some suggestion on this problem?

Thanks.